# PHP move_uploaded_file not working into public server

Tags: php, image, upload

I am trying to upload my php project into public server.
I made the image upload file when I create product or edit product.
It works in localhost, but when I move to public server, it is not working.
I think move_uploaded_file part does not working.
How can I change the link? or do I have to change anything?
When I see Filzilla, I can see remote site that it is '/www/eshopProject/inventory_images'.
And index file is '/www/eshopProject/storeAdmin'.
Do I have to change link like this?
I don't know how can I change the link.
Could you help me? uploading the image into public server is not working..
Is it any security issue? or something?
Please help me. Thanks.

--index.php--

```
$pid = mysql_insert_id();
//Place image in the folder
$newname = "$pid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/product_$newname");
```

Comment: What are the folder's permissions?

Comment: ... has to be something like 777 or less depending on user

Comment: almost sure the full path is not "/www/eshopProject/inventory_images", but you are using a relative path, it should be fine if you are running the script the same way.. enable error reporting and see what's wrong.. it could be caused by a lot of reasons like: writing permissions, server limitations for file size, uploads disabled on that server and others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all check the permissions of the directory as mentioned in come of the comments.
If you have shell access "chmod 777 target_dir" or "chmod 707 target_dir" should be sufficient.

Second try to debug it using if's and the file_exists function(http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Something like this.

```
$uploadedFile = $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'];
$destination = "../inventory_images/product_$newname";

if(file_exists($uploadedFile))
{
   echo "file uploaded to temp dir";
}
else
{
   echo "file upload failed";
   exit();
}

if(move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile, $destination))
{
   echo "upload complete";
}
else
{
   echo "move_uploaded_file failed";
   exit();
}
```

You can also check your current working directory by using the **FILE** or **DIR** constants(http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Try this.

```
echo __FILE__;
echo dirname(__FILE__);
echo __DIR__;
```

Comment: Oh. I changed the permission to 777 this folder, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `copy()` method. For me it worked.

```
copy($tmp_file, Destination) or
copy($tmp_image, IMAGE_DIRECTORY . SAM . $product_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have write file permissions set to the folder you are trying to upload too.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting the folders to "755" permissions and retry. This would make the permissions a little tighter.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but i recently faced a similar issue where even with permission 777 on the upload folder it wouldn't work.
The issue was that the SELinux (https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) was on enforcing mode so i had to change it to permissive mode and then the upload works perfectly.
I hope this can help someone facing this issue.

Comment: Surely it is better to properly configure SELinux than to disable it ("permissive mode"). It exists for a reason (enforcing security on your server). One could for example add a `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` context for all /upload/ directories and their contents: `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t  "/home/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/upload(/.*)?"`

Comment: @MarkusAO thank you for the tip, i will surely give it a try. I found a nice article explaining this https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/